# How to check if JTextField is NOT editable

Tags: java, boolean, jtextfield

Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm not entirely sure how I check if a JTextField is not editable?

I know that to check if it is editable, you just use

```
JTextField.isEditable();
```

but how do I check if it is not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to Java docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#isEditable%28%29), isEditable:

> Returns the boolean indicating whether this TextComponent is editable
>   or not.

So, I guess you could just:

```
if (yourInstance.isEditable() == false) {
    // Your action here
}
```

Or even:

```
if (!yourInstance.isEditable()) {
    // Your action here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the logical complement operator (NOT):

```
if ( !textField.isEditable()){
    .
    .
    .
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html